# MutableLiveData.observe is not trigger in Android API 23

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have created one viewModel class with MutableLiveData and then I try to observe in MainActivity like below

ViewModel Code

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
public MutableLiveData<BaseResponse> loginResponse() {
    return responseLiveData;
}

public void doLogin(){

disposables.add(networkRepository.executeLogin(jsonLoginRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe((d) -> 
 responseLiveData.setValue(BaseResponse.loading()))
            .subscribe(
                    result -> {

 responseLiveData.setValue(BaseResponse.success(result));
                    },
                    throwable -> {

responseLiveData.setValue(BaseResponse.error(throwable));
                    }
            ));
```

}

Activity Code

```
 loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel.class);

    loginViewModel.loginResponse().observe(this, new Observer<BaseResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable BaseResponse baseResponse) {
            processResponse(baseResponse); not trigger at any point.
        }
    });
```

It is working fine in the Android 26,27 and 28 but not in the 21 and 23.

Comment: Have you checked about **API call** is happening or not? Another thing is how you're providing `ViewModelFactory`?

Comment: Try using `responseLiveData.postValue()` instead of `setValue()`

Comment: This isn't a minimal verifiable and complete example, is it? How can we reproduce this?